# search for a words in a text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file containing records of staff, I want to search for a `EMP_NO` and return the record of the user with the inputted `EMP_NO`. I tried to take the example from a python book I bought and change it to my needs but when I type in an EMP_NO it goes straight to my 'if not found' statement and says it doesn't exist.

```
data = open('Records.txt', 'r')
found = False
search = input("Enter the UserID of the record you want to find: ")
user_id = data.readline()

while user_id != '':
    user_id = user_id.rstrip('\n')

    if search == user_id:
        print('User_ID', user_id)
        print()
        found = True
    user_id = data.readline()

if not found:
    print("The UserID entered does not exist.")
```

An example of one of the records inside my record file:

```
#EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, AGE, POSITION, SALARY, YRS_EMP   
001, Peter Smyth, 26, Developer, 29000, 4
002, Samuel Jones, 23, Developer, 24000, 1
003, Laura Stewart, 41, DevOps, 42000, 15
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: where are you splittingtheline? why should `'001, Peter Smyth, 26, Developer, 29000, 4'` ever equal `whatever you input?`

Comment: did you actually debug your code? f.e. by printing the things you compare to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file with a simple `open`:

```
data = open('myfile.csv').read().splitlines()
```

Then you can use a list comprehension:

```
EMP_NO = '001'
record = [l for l in data if l.split(',')[0] == EMP_NO][0]
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain what the record line is doing?